# neobundle インストール

Tags: linux, vim

お世話になっております。現在、会社のPC(インターネットアクセスが制限されています)
https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim

こちらのサイトからcloneではなく、zipでダウンロードしてzipファイルをサーバーに置き
~/.vim/bundle/neobundle/
配下にzipを展開済み
.vimrcに

```
if has('vim_starting')
  set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim
  call neobundle#rc(expand('~/.vim/bundle'))
endif
```

と書いたのですが、runtimepathのpath指定がディレクトリ構成と違うので変更したいと考えています。
しかし、neobundle.vimはaoutload、pluginの中にもあります。
どこのディレクトリのneobundle.vimを指定すれば良いでしょうか？

また、nerdtreeを追加したいと思っているのですが、ネット上ではPCがインターネットに繋がっているためvimrcにプラグインの追加として記入していますが、こちらの環境ではネットに繋ぐ手段がないのでできないのではと考えております。

PCがネットに繋がらなくても使えるようにする方法はありますでしょうか？

駄文で分かり辛いと思いますが、ご教授願い致します。

環境
Linux 
CentOS 5.6

Answer (score 1):

> どこのディレクトリのneobundle.vimを指定すれば良いでしょうか？

`set runtimepath`では、`.vim`で終わるファイルではなく、ディレクトリを指定します。

`plugin/`や`autoload/`が入っているディレクトリを指定してください。

（neobundleの設定例で`neobundle.vim`になっているのは、リポジトリ名が`neobundle.vim`だからでしょう。ちょっとややこしいですよね。）

> また、nerdtreeを追加したいと思っているのですが、ネット上ではPCがインターネットに繋がっているためvimrcにプラグインの追加として記入していますが、こちらの環境ではネットに繋ぐ手段がないのでできないのではと考えております。
>
> PCがネットに繋がらなくても使えるようにする方法はありますでしょうか？

自分でローカルに配置したプラグインをNeoBundleで管理する方法として回答してみます。

nerdtreeをzipで持ち込んで展開し、`~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree`として配置し、

```
NeoBundle '~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree', { 'type': 'none' }
```

すれば使えるようになると思います。

ですが、neobundleを使わなくても、使いたいプラグインのzipをダウンロードして展開してどこかに配置し、先ほどと同様に、`plugin/`や`autoload/`が入っているディレクトリを`set runtimepath+=`で追加すれば、使えるようになりますので、それで十分では、と思います。